# Silex setup fails with MAMP because mod_access.so is not found?

Tags: php, apache, mamp, silex, mod-access

I have downloaded [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) and I am trying to get it running with MAMP. However, when I run Silex (and **only** when I run Silex), Apache won't start. In the console, I see:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 238 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_access.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_access.so, 10): image not found
logout`

Googling the error leads to info that suggests this is a known bug, but I can't find what to actually *do* about it.

Silex temporarily changes my httpd.conf from [this](http://pastebin.com/53rL9gbY) to [this](http://pastebin.com/UsKSuvBW) while it's running. After it changes back, upon quitting Silex, Apache starts again.

Apache is version 2.2.22.

Comment: Can you show use your apache config for this website? What version of apache are you using?

Comment: Except `ServerName cn.som.loc` becoming `ServerName de.client.loc` I don't see any difference. Is that normal? You have all your configuration in the httpd.conf?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to anonymize some data and it looks like I missed one domain. I don't know what you mean by "You have all your configuration in httpd.conf" but the virtual hosts aren't the part that changes when Silex runs.

Comment: So if both files are the same Silex doesn't change your httpd.conf right? When you say that when you run Silex, Apache doesn't start, what do you mean by 'run Silex'?